# NGINX + Kestrel - Can't upload files in multipart/formdata

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core-1.1, kestrel

I have a .NET Core app that has a form for uploading files. It works fine in IIS but when I deploy to Nginx (as a reverse proxy) on Ubuntu, file uploads time out or result in a bad gateway error. I'm unable to see where I can investigate the problem further, the nginx access logs and the output from Kestrel aren't very helpful.

Here's my nginx config, I suspect that it's not passing the data to Kestrel

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://dotnet;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
```

The frustrating thing is that despite giving a 504 and taking 60 seconds to complete an upload operation of a small file, the file still makes it to the server.

What nginx config option am I missing? I'm suspecting that kestrel isn't supplying a http response to nginx.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question. The problem was with the "keep alive" connection header of the WebApi that was handling the file upload.

The project I'm working on uses Websockets and WebApis. Generally these two things don't go together - the websocket code requires a constant server connection (through "keep alive" header) whereas the webapi doesn't. The WebApi response was never having due to the "keep alive" header. I created a rule to treat the WebApi traffic as normal non-"keep alive" and the issue resolved itself.

Comment: I encountered the same problem, can you please give a configuration?